# Bash: tree direction in sub-shell working incorrectly

Tags: bash, stderr, tee

I tested this on a CentOS machine a while back and it worked nicely. Now on another machine, I try this and it fails to work. What is incorrect?

```
command 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2) && exit
```

I get this message back.

```
sh: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message. The traditional Bourne shell (`sh`) doesn't support process substitution (e.g. `>(command)`). You weren't using Bash. You can change your default shell using the `chsh` command.

Comment: @hexacyanide Yes, on many systems `sh` is actually `bash`, but there are several compatibility modes in `bash` and they often depend on the way the shell was started. So even if `sh` uses `bash` inside, its behavior will often be different than if you invoked it as `bash`. If this is inside a script, you should solve your problem by changing the shebang line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @hexacyanide: Note, however, that on Ubuntu `/bin/sh` means `dash`, not `bash`.

Comment: @hexacyanide: What OS or distribution are you using on the system where you got the error?

Comment: @hexacyanide: CentOS uses `bash` symlinked to `sh` which is equivalent to running `bash --posix`. These modes do not support process substitution.