# difference between user@host and sh-4.1$ (with GNU screen)

Tags: php, bash, centos

When I use

```
2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
```

in a shell with sh-4.1$ prepending the command, it doesn't work. However, if the beginning shows username@hostname, it works.

Also - this is while opening screen with PHP. How should I change my script for this to work?
The script is:

```
php exec("screen -S SCREENNAME -p 0 -X stuff 'COMMAND 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash tee and redirection not working anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990314/bash-tee-and-redirection-not-working-anymore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your prompt has "sh" at the beginning, it's bash running in **sh compatibility mode**, which *does not* have process substitution. Your command *must* be run via bash; run `bash -c` and pass the command to run as a string.

Comment: Not reliably. Invoke bash explicitly.